# Sending notification to the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I want to write a website chat program.In this program,Someone invite another to start chat if she/he accepts request ,server should notify the inviter and then chat starts. I dont know how can i send an invitation to other user and then send the reply of it to inviter.Also when the inviter sends the chat request,one record will be inserted into the Database.Is web service a good idea?What should i write in my web service?what method should i write or Is there a way that i can handle it in my web sites code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into SignalR
http://signalr.net/

It's a push framework for pushing messages from the server to the client.
You can send to one or multiple users.

Comment: @user369362 The [classic SignalR tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20) is actually based on chat.

Comment: Thanks.It help me .Can i send file instead of text by using SignalR

Comment: At the very least you can use signalR to create a link on the page that the user can click to download a file through a regular http request.

Comment: I want to do this with web service.It is not easy for me to work with SignalR.I write web service but I dont know how can i notificate to other users